# Anchor link inside bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstaps tabs. I now need a link from one tab to the other at the end of the content (From the #allmembers to #additional

```
          <div class="contact-content">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs contactTab">
                <li class="allmembers">
                   <a href="#allmembers" data-toggle="tab">Members</a>
                </li>
                <li class="additional">
                   <a href="#additional" data-toggle="tab">Additional</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="allmembers">
                  Content
                </div>                    

                <div class="tab-pane active" id="additional">
                  Content 2
                </div>
            </div>
```

JQuery

```
   $('.contactTab a:first').tab('show') // Select first tab

   $('.contactTab a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).tab('show');
   });
```

I can get the anchor link set up ok but it doesn't then switch the tab over and scroll to the top. I expect that's something to do with preventing the Default behaviour.

Comment: use [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) not .tab('show')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pbQqT/1/) that do the job.

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $('[href="#additional"]').tab('show');
});
```

Your mistake is at the jQuery selector level i think.

Enjoy :)